# What kind of hosting/server do i need? Run bins and redirect with ASP.NET

Tags: hosting, asp.net

The title says most of it.

I need a server or hosting plan to run ASP.NET projects. I found one (free test) that couldn't redirect URLs unless it end with .aspx and another that didnt allow to be create files or read/write to them. Then  i'll need to use imagemagik to make thumbs and ffmpeg to convert .ogg to .mp3.

I know using heavy scripts are forbidden on most hosting providers but i run them in low priority and this is to be done once in a while. Also it takes longer to upload a sound file then to convert them (although i won't depend on this).

What kind of hosting plan do i need? i was told by one that i cannot using a hosting plan and need a VPS. I would hate to configure a server. Can Linux run any ASP.NET projects? or is that not supported yet?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you take a look at [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/). Prices start at free and it's a fully managed platform for deploying and scaling your .NET applications. We recommend against writing content to instance file stystems (for scalability reasons), so you should modify your application accordingly (we recommend using Amazon S3).

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a Windows hosting package. A shared hosting package sounds right for you and should be in the neighbordhood of $5-15/month based on your disk and bandwidth needs.

You can checkout my company, we do this kind of hosting: www.servermotion.com

You can also talk to other hosts in the industry:

www.godaddy.com
www.hosting.com
www.hostgator.com

Good luck!